# Is target type necessary in dynamic casting?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Looking at the following expression:

```
Target * p = dynamic_cast<Target*>(pFarAncestor);
```

Is there a case where the dynamic conversion type could differ from the left value (p in this case) type? There's a reason, in other words, for explicit all the times the type of the destination variable?

I wonder why compilers do not accept a contracted form like:

```
Target * p = dynamic_cast<>(pFarAncestor);
```

or even

```
Target * p = dynamic_cast(pFarAncestor); // ok this seems a function call indeed
```

Comment: They do, it's [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

Comment: Re: *"ok this seems a function call indeed"*. The return types of functions don't participate in template argument deduction (which is what you are essentially asking).

Comment: @StoryTeller The function could return a proxy, with a conversion operator that does the dynamic cast. (Not that I am advocating for that...)

Comment: @MarcGlisse - It could, but the trade off is that now we can't call the function like `foo<type>` anymore. We lose the explicit control.

Comment: We could always have both versions, that's not really a strong issue.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - No we can't. As far as I recall, having both would cause an ambiguity. (And do tag me if you respond, I wasn't notified, came here by chance)

Comment: @StoryTeller 1) dynamic_cast is magic, so it can always be special-cased 2) we don't have to use the same name for the 2 variants 3) it does seem possible even for regular function (see next comment). I am still not saying we need this.

Comment: `struct use_proxy; template<class P>struct Proxy{P p;template<class T>operator T()const{return dynamic_cast<T>(p);}}; template<class T,class P>struct Helper{static T f(P p){return dynamic_cast<T>(p);}}; template<class P>struct Helper<use_proxy,P>{static Proxy<P> f(P p){return {p};}}; template<class T=use_proxy,class U>auto f(U*p){return Helper<T,U*>::f(p);} struct A{virtual ~A(){}}; struct B:A{}; B* x(A*p){return f<B*>(p);} B* y(A*p){return f(p);}` (just a proof of concept, not meant to be pretty or used for real)

Comment: @MarcGlisse - (2) If we aren't using the same name, they aren't the same operator. (3) That comment makes a mess I can't read. Since I'm on my phone and AFK, you'll pardon me if I don't comment about its merits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) keyword has mainly been introduced for this reason:

```
auto p = dynamic_cast<Target*>(pFarAncestor);
```

If you really want to avoid repeating the type on the right side of the expression, you could use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), it is a little bit more verbose though:

```
Target * p = dynamic_cast<decltype(p)>(pFarAncestor);
```

But you obviously have to write the type at least once somewhere.

Comment: auto could be the right solution for a local use. The real need was to eliminate redundant types because is quite obvious that, if I have a Target* member of my class as left operand, a dynamic cast will try to convert the ancestor to that type. Maybe the second form could be contracted by a macro (with other drawbacks) like 
 DYNAMIC(dest,src) dest=dynamic_cast<decltype(dest)>(src)

Comment: @Cappelli Could also be a function template if you want to avoid macros:  
`template<typename Dest, typename Src>
Dest&      hide_cast(Dest& dest, const Src& src)
{
  dest = dynamic_cast<Dest>(src);
  return dest;
}`

Answer (score 4):

To answer "Is there a case where the dynamic conversion type could differ from the left value (p in this case) type?" one can construct many examples, and fairly useful one is:

```
bool hasTargetAncestor = dynamic_cast<Target*>(pFarAncestor);
```

Assignments would be another case:

```
shared_ptr<Target> p;
...
  p = dynamic_cast<Target*>(pFarAncestor);
```

As already noted using `auto` for the declaration avoids the repetition in a better way - in the many cases where it is the same.